# SQL - getting data for the time frame from daily snapshots

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data written i DB as daily snapshots. The tables are

```
DECISION_REFUSAL_REASON_STATS
    -REASON_STTS_ID (fk_reasons_stats_id)
    -PERIOD_ID (fk_period_id)
    -REFUSAL_REASON_CODE
    -REFUSAL_COUNT

REASONS_STATS
    -ID
    -REF_MANUFACTURER
    -REF_PRODUCT_CODE
    -REF_WARRANTY_CODE

PERIOD
    -ID
    -EXACT_DATE
```

Period table is more complex but for the purpose of the question should be enough. As it is now, it is just an association of date (yyyy-mm-dd) to an id which is used as foreign key in  `DECISION_REFUSAL_REASON_STATS`.

This table (`DECISION_REFUSAL_REASON_STATS`) contains daily snapshots of the current situation , constructed in such a way, that for each day from `PERIOD` table it stores stats about refusal reason. Now, on particular day, there might be more than one refusal reason, and only those that were updated are stored.

i.e.

```
day 1 (as first day of the whole period)
-------
bad writing: 2 
incorrect receipt: 1 

day 2
-------
bad writing: 3 
to late: 1

day 3
-------
to late: 3 
incorrect receipt: 2 

=====================
```

I need to generate stats between day 2 and 3 so the expected result would be:

```
Result (day 3 - day 1 stats)
-------
to late: 3
incorrect receipt: 2 - 1 = 1
bad writing: 3 - 2 = 1
```

As you can see, it is not just a matter of subtracting day 1 data from day 3 data. I need to account for those missing reasons on day 3.

I managed to get the stats for the last day of the period

```
SELECT
  RS.REF_WARRANTY_CODE
, DRRS_END.REFUSAL_REASON_CODE
, MAX(NVL(DRRS_END.REFUSAL_COUNT, 0))  
FROM
  DECISION_REFUSAL_REASON_STATS DRRS_END 
  JOIN REASON_STATS RS ON (DRRS_END.REASON_STTS_ID = RS.ID)
  LEFT JOIN PERIOD P_END ON (DRRS_END.PERIOD_ID = P_END.ID)
WHERE 
  P_END.EXACT_DATE <= TO_DATE('2013-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY 
  CS.REF_GUARANTEES_CODE
, CRRS_END.REFUSAL_REASON_CODE
ORDER BY
  CS.REF_GUARANTEES_CODE
```

, but am stuck on how to progress with further and subtract 'Period start' data so my question is - how can I achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you subtracting "to late" as you did the other reasons, but I'll consider that an oversight, and that you really did want to do that. What you really want, as I understand it, is: "As of today, what was the last change in reasons?" (I might amend that to fit your results by saying, "Keep today, plus any change between today and the start day, plus any change between a previous day and the start day.") I think you need a compound query to get this, something like: (and you don't mention version, so I'm going with 10g) (column names abbreviated):

SELECT y.refusal_code, 
y.refusal_count – nvl(x.refusal_count,0) change_from_today,
z.refusal_code, z.refusal_count – nvl(x.refusal_count,0) change_from_prev_day_not_today
from 
( select * from stats where period_id = ( select current period from period table ) y
left outer JOIN
( select * from stats where period_id = ( select start period from period table ) x
left outer JOIN
( select * from stats where not exists ( select 1 from stats where period = current )
and period_id = ( select max(period) from stats where period < current period ) z

Note: y query gives you reasons from current period being compared
x query gives you reasons from start period to compare to
z query gives you reasons before current period - whether they were in start period or not.